# Error in twitter4j classes while feeding data from twitter using flume

Tags: twitter4j, cloudera, flume

I am using the sources provided by cloudera flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT uploaded on github.

I am getting error below. the method does not exist in the configuration.class the jar provided by cloudera in twitter4j.

How to solve this issue?

```
 {    

    14/06/12 03:04:56 INFO node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider:                                             Configuration provider starting
    14/06/12 03:04:56 INFO node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Reloading configuration file:conf/tagent
    14/06/12 03:04:56 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:HDFS
    14/06/12 03:04:56 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:HDFS
    14/06/12 03:04:56 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:HDFS
    14/06/12 03:04:56 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Added sinks: HDFS Agent: TwitterAgent
    14/06/12 03:04:56 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:HDFS
    14/06/12 03:04:56 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:HDFS
    14/06/12 03:04:56 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:HDFS
    14/06/12 03:04:56 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:HDFS
    14/06/12 03:04:56 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:HDFS
    14/06/12 03:04:56 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [TwitterAgent]
    14/06/12 03:04:56 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Creating channels
    14/06/12 03:04:56 INFO channel.DefaultChannelFactory: Creating instance of channel MemChannel type memory
    14/06/12 03:04:57 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Created channel MemChannel
    14/06/12 03:04:57 INFO source.DefaultSourceFactory: Creating instance of source Twitter, type com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
    14/06/12 03:04:57 ERROR node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Unhandled error
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:         twitter4j.conf.Configuration.getRequestHeaders()Ljava/util/Map;
at         twitter4j.StreamingReadTimeoutConfiguration.getRequestHeaders(TwitterStreamImpl.java:664)
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.<init>(HttpClientWrapper.java:47)
at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl.<init>(TwitterStreamImpl.java:54)
at twitter4j.TwitterStreamFactory.<clinit>(TwitterStreamFactory.java:40)
at com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource.<init>(TwitterSource.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
at org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory.create(DefaultSourceFactory.java:42)
at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:327)
at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:102)
at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
at  java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the twitter4j jars version you are using.

twitter4j.conf.Configuration.getRequestHeaders() method is not in the latest versions.

But it is in twitter4j 2.x

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace all the  twitter4j-3.0.3 libraries placed in `flume/lib` folder by the `twitter4j-2.x.x` version. The reason is that same class name is conflicting in `twitter4j-3.0.3` and `flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

To avoid this you have to make changes in the twitter4j properties by putting the following property in `twitter4j.properties` as class path:

```
streamBaseURL=https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/ `
```

**Or** you can download the new flume-source-1.0-snapshot.jar from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qvudqfym5givwdg/flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar?dl=0).

This issue has been resolved by the Twitter community, for a full explanation you can check [this discussion](https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-streaming-api-not-working-with-twitter4j-and-apache-flume/66612).

Answer (score 0):

When you receive

```
twitter4j.conf.Configuration.getRequestHeaders() method error.
```

Try below steps, it resolved my issue.

1. Remove the below 3 jar files from `/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/ directory`.

   - twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar
   - twitter4j-media-support-3.0.3.jar
   - twitter4j-stream-3.0.3.jar
2. Add the below jar files to `/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/ directory`.
   (`twitter4j` jars should be latest version.)

   - flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
   - twitter4j-core-4.0.7.jar
   - twitter4j-async-4.0.7.jar
   - twitter4j-stream-4.0.7.jar